# Architecture of Real-Time "Card Game" App

Tags: oop, design-patterns, web-applications, architecture, multiplayer

I'm building a clone of the popular game Cards Against Humanity, for learning purposes. I was wondering if anyone could help me structure a plan for the app. I want to use AngularJS on the frontend, and interface with a node server via websockets, so I can have realtime interactions between players, i.e., a game chat room, and the ability to "see" when other players have made their choices (real-time pubsub with websockets and node?).

I know these types of 'non-deterministic' questions tend to be difficult to answer, but if anyone could give some advice, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Edit: Tech advice is good, but I really need some insight as to the design of the application, and what patterns I should research.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the http://yeoman.io for learn about the structures. He s a "architect".

You can install

```
npm install -g yo
```

and now you can install some app-generator, if you want angular + nodejs. I suggest this one.

```
npm install -g generator-angular-fullstack
```

now you can run

```
yo angular-fullstack [app-name]
```

//For start the server

```
grunt serve
```

or

```
cd server
node app.js
```

good learn!